# lvalue and rvalue for pre/postfix increment

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue

Learning the lvalue and rvalue. The definition is whatever that can be "address of" is the left value and otherwise, it is rvalue.

I checked the operator precedence, both prefix and postfix increment has higher priority than the "address of" operator.

For the following two examples, can anyone explain a bit why the first one "&++value1" is a lvalue while the second one "&value1++" is a rvalue.

My wrong understanding for both case is: pValue1 is pointing to the value1 variable. No matter value1 is changed to 8 before or after the address correlation is built, the value1 variable always occupies one memory location and we can derive its address, right?

```
int value1=7;

int *pValue1=&++value1;

int *pValue1 = &value1++;
```

Comment: postfix `operator++` returns a preincremented copy, not a reference to incremented object

Comment: Not directly related, but your definition of 'lvalue' is incomplete. Bitfields are lvalues, but you can't get their addresses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on my comment you can see why the compiler is against this kind of operation. The problem lies in general implementation of postfix `operator ++`, which copies the object (`int` in this case), increments the original one and returns that **preincremented copy**. You can think of it like of a function that is defined in following way:

```
int foo_operator(int& a)
{
    int copy = a;
    a += 1;
    return copy;
}
```

If you try to use that function in your example, your compiler will also protest against it. The return value of that function is an **rvalue**.

You might now ask - *what's up with the prefix `operator ++`? Isn't that also a function that returns a value?* And the answer would be - **no**. Prefix `operator ++` returns **a reference**, not a copied value, thus the 'outcome' of it can be used with operand `&`.

Comment: More specifically, `i++` is a prvalue expression.